# NoReverseMatch Django using pk

Tags: python, django

Reverse for 'update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['basic_app/update/(?P[0-9]+)/\Z']

```
9     <p>Location: {{school_detail.location}} </p>
10    <h3>Students:</h3>
11    {% for student in school_detail.students.all %}
12    <p>{{student.name}} who is {{student.age}} years old</p>
13    {% endfor %}
14  
15  
16  </div>
17  
18  <div class="container">
19  <p><a class='btn btn-warning' href="{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school_details.pk %}">Update</a></p> 
20  
21  </div>
22  {% endblock %}
```

Here is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from basic_app import views
app_name='basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
    path('create/',views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(),name='create'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/',views.SchoolUpdateView.as_view(),name='update'),
    ]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show urls.py, you need to include `pk` in the path.

Comment: Change the anchor tag to `<p><a class='btn btn-warning' href="{% url 'basic_app:update' school_details.pk %}">Update</a></p>`.  Maybe you wanted to pass pk as a parameter and not a keyword argument?

Comment: @raphael I tried but gives the same error mate

Comment: Add your view, maybe I can see where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo:

```
{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school_details.pk %}
```

Should be:

```
{% url 'basic_app:update' pk=school_detail.pk %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
href="{% url 'basic_app:update' school_detail.pk %}"
```